# CSS - select columns 2-6 of current row?

Tags: css

I want a hover effect so when the user hovers over any columns between 1 and 7 of a row, these styles apply to all columns in the row except columns 1 and 7 (so the background color changes on the current row, columns 2-6, but NOT columns 1 and 7):

```
tbody tr:hover > td:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
    cursor: pointer; background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
}
```

However, I ALSO have a similar hover style on columns 1 and 7. So, to clarify, the desired behaviour is:

1. User hovers over row x, column 1 - that single cell gets the hover effect.
2. User hovers over row x, column 7 - that single cell gets the hover effect.
3. User hovers over row x, any column from 2-6, ALL cells in row x, columns 2-6 get the hover effect.

Comment: why not just set the style and then override it for first-child and last-child.  and in your css, you should be putting the nth-child on the td

Comment: are you using SASS or plain CSS ?

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution as "Pete" commented:
css:

```
tbody tr:not(:first-child):not(:last-child){
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
}
```

on td elemenst for every row

```
tbody tr td:not(:first-child):not(:last-child){
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
}
```

So we need to use some jQuery to archieve that for the cells from 2 to 6 use some class ot tds, and regular css for the first child and last child

```js
$("table.mytable").find('td.a')
  .on( "mouseenter", function() {
   var allaclass = $(this).parent().find('td.a');
    allaclass.css("background-color", "red");
  })
  .on( "mouseleave", function() {
    var allaclass = $(this).parent().find('td.a');
    allaclass.css("background-color", "white");
  });
```

```css
tbody tr td:first-child:hover,
tbody tr td:last-child:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="mytable"> 
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="a">2</td>
      <td class="a">3</td>
      <td class="a">4</td>
      <td class="a">5</td>
      <td class="a">6</td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="a">2</td>
      <td class="a">3</td>
      <td class="a">4</td>
      <td class="a">5</td>
      <td class="a">6</td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: OK this has got my on the right track: `tbody tr:hover td:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)`, however I'd like columns 1 and 7 to have their OWN hover style, but now if I hover over columns 1 or 7, the whole TR gets the style.

Comment: tbody tr:hover > td:not(:first-child):not(:last-child){
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
}

Comment: No change. extra characters

Answer (score 1):

Apply the **hover to the parent**.

```
tbody:hover tr:not(:nth-child(1)):not(:nth-child(7)) {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
}
```

```css
tbody:hover tr:not(:nth-child(1)):not(:nth-child(7)) {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you want to do it on the td